# Finite blowup time for a simple ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the ODE

$$ y'(x) = C y(x)^{2-x},$$

where $C$ is a positive constant.  I suspect there is no closed-form solution.  I want to understand the constant $C$ such that for a given $y(0) > 0$, the solution blows up at $x=1$: $y(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow 1$.  For example, if $y(0)=1$, then $C \approx 2.79301$ works (from numerical solution).

Comment: To characterize in what terms? I hope you don't expect anyone to provide an explicit elementary formula  $C=F(y(0))$ for the least possible $C$..

Comment: Characterizing $C$ in any sense would be good.  Or just proving that there exists a finite $C$ such that the solution blows up at $x=1$.  I edited the question to reflect this.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, the existence is obvious: for large $C$ the blow-up occurs before $1$, for small $C$ there is no blow-up, there is the trivial monotonicity, and the set of $C$ for which there is no blow-up on the closed interval $[0,T]$ is open for every fixed $T>0$.